# Teste de correlação em dados categóricos com baixo número de contagens

Tags: r

Rodei um teste de correlação no R e o p-value foi `NA`. Alguém pode me explicar isso?

Estava correlacionando a escolaridade com a ocupação trabalhista da pessoa. Alguns dados de ocupação trabalhista estão em falta (`NA` na tabela) é devido a isso? se for como devo proceder para rodar o novo teste?
O comando que executei foi:

```
dput(head(bruno$ocupacao, 20))
structure(c(4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("agricultora_e_artesa", 
"aposentado", "atv.domesticas", "campo", "prof.liberais"), class = "factor")
dput(head(bruno$tempo.esc, 20))
structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("analfabeto", "fund.completo", 
"fund.incompleto", "med.completo", "med.incompleto"), class = "factor") 

    Tabela2<-table(dados$ocupacao,dados$tempo.esc)

    chisq.test(Tabela2)
    ## Pearson's Chi-squared test
    ## data:  Tabela2
    ## X-squared = NaN, df = 16, p-value = NA
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados, 20))`?

Comment: dput(head(bruno$ocupacao, 20))
structure(c(4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("agricultora_e_artesa",
"aposentado", "atv.domesticas", "campo", "prof.liberais"), class = "factor")
dput(head(bruno$tempo.esc, 20))
structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L,
3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("analfabeto", "fund.completo",
"fund.incompleto", "med.completo", "med.incompleto"), class = "factor")

Answer (score 1):

A quantidade de casos é muito baixa em diversas caselas (muitas contém o valor `0`, por exemplo).

A mensagem de *alerta* quando vocẽ aplica o `chisq.test` é:

> Warning message:
>
> In chisq.test(Tabela2) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

O aviso acima ocorre porque diversos valores esperados serão muito pequenos e, assim, os `p-values` podem não ser corretos (`chisq.test` é geralmente usado quando você tem contagens maiores).

No entanto, uma alternativa a isso é usar o teste exato de Fisher (por convenção, se a contagem for abaixo de 5, use `fisher.test`):

```
fisher.test(Tabela2)

#   Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

#data:  Tabela2
#p-value = 0.109
#alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```